# Integrating Stripe in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, integration, stripe-payments

I've been trying pretty much all ways to Integrate Stripe Library onto my Codeigniter App

I Tried Placing the Downloaded lib in `application/libraries/Stripe` & `system/libraries/Stripe`

Download Link : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php..

There is not much Info on how to load the Library..

Below is the Code straight from Stripe's PHP Documentation
https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "Example charge"
    ));
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
}
```

How do i Load this library because as of Now i get an error while i try to load it with the above code

Any help?

EDIT

This is how i included the Lib in Controller

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/stripe/init.php');
```

Comment: What error r u getting??

Comment: The blue "Pay with Card" Button works.. But the next process : Charging the card... url messes up

Not Found

The requested URL /charge was not found on this server.

Comment: You should put the stripe directory in another directory rather than Libraries. CodeIgniter looks for specifically named files in Libraries.

Comment: Also, take a look at Composer. It's a package manager for PHP and works great with CodeIgniter. You will add one single autoload line in your index.php file and then composer can install/upgrade Stripe's bindings (and any other libraries you might want!)

Comment: you can also use omnipay to integrate stripe as it would be easy to integrate due to composer. All you need to do is just include the autoload.php of composer and rest is easy to handle check this link: https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay

if you need working example ill show you.....

Comment: you should load libraries in CI with $this->load->library('filename');

Answer (score 1):

The Stripe documentation can get a little squirrely until you get used to it. I find that the endpoint PHP docs are much better. I opted to write my own library to do things with Stripe rather than using their download SDK. If you compare some of what's below with their documentation, it may get you pointed in the right direction to expound upon.

#### /application/libaries/stripe.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Stripe {

    const PROCESS_URL = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1';
    const API_KEY = '{YOUR-STRIPE-API-KEY}'; 

    public $CI;
    public $db;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | CONSTRUCT
    | (In case you need access to the CI Instance
    |--------------------------------------------
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =   &get_instance();
        $this->db =   $this->CI->db;
    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | CREATE CUSTOMER
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function create_customer($request) {
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers';     
        return $this->post_request($process_url, $request); 
    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | GET CUSTOMER
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function get_customer($cus_id) {
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id;     
        $customer_obj = $this->post_request($process_url); 
        $customer_arr = json_decode($customer_obj);

        return $customer_arr;

    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | GET CUSTOMER
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function get_default_source($cus_id) {
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id;     
        $customer_obj = $this->post_request($process_url); 
        $customer_arr = json_decode($customer_obj);
        $card_id = $customer_arr->default_source;

        return $card_id;

    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | GET CARD
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function get_card($cus_id,$card_id) {
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id.'/cards/'.$card_id;     
        $card_obj = $this->post_request($process_url); 

        return $this->decode_response($card_obj);

    }

    /*
    |-----------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | ADD CARD
    | Params: Stripe Customer ID, Card Data Object
    |-----------------------------------------------
    */
    public function add_card($cus_id,$card_data) {
        $request = array(
            'source' => $card_data
        );
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id.'/sources';     
        $card_json = $this->post_request($process_url,$request); 
        $card_obj = json_decode($card_json);

        // successful?
        if(isset($card_obj->id)) {
            $ret_arr = array(
                'status' => true,
                'response' => $card_obj
            );
        } else {
            $ret_arr = array(
                'status' => false,
                'error' => $card_obj->error->message
            );   
        }

        return $ret_arr;

    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | ADD CARD
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function subscribe_customer($cus_id,$plan_id,$source) {
        $request['plan'] = $plan_id;
        if($source) { $request['source'] = $source; }
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id.'/subscriptions';     
        $plan_json = $this->post_request($process_url,$request); 
        $plan_obj = json_decode($plan_json);

        // successful?
        if(isset($plan_obj->id)) {
            $ret_arr = array(
                'status' => true,
                'response' => $plan_obj
            );
        } else {
            $ret_arr = array(
                'status' => false,
                'error' => $plan_obj->error->message
            );   
        }

        return $ret_arr;

    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | DECODE JSON RESPONSE
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function decode_response($response) {
        return json_decode($response);
    }


    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | POST REQUESTS
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function post_request($url, $data = NULL)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);

        if (is_array($data))
        {
            $data = http_build_query($data);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        return $this->do_curl_request($ch);
    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | CURL REQUEST
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    private function do_curl_request($ch)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, self::API_KEY);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);

        if($response) {

        } else {
            var_dump($error);    
        }

        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }

}
```

#### Create a New Customer

```
// Create Stripe Customer
$request = array(
    "description" => "{DESCRIPTION}",
    "metadata" => array(
        'First Name' => "{FIRST NAME}",
        'Last Name' => "{LAST NAME}",
        'Company Name' => "{COMPANY NAME}"
    ),
    "shipping" => array(
        "name" => "{NAME}",
        "address" => array (
            "city" => "{CITY}",
            "state" => "{STATE}",
            "postal_code" => "{POSTAL CODE}",
            "line1" => "{STREET ADDRES}",
            "line2" => "{STREET ADDRESS 2}",
        )
    ),
    "email" => "{SOME EMAIL ADDRESS}"
);

$this->load->library( 'stripe' );
$response = $this->stripe->create_customer( $request );
$response_arr = $this->stripe->decode_response( $response );
$data['stripe_customer_id'] = $response_arr->id;
```

#### Add a Payment Source

```
$card_object = array(
    "object"        => 'card',

    "address_city"  => "{BILLING CITY}",
    "address_state" => "{BILLING STATE}",
    "address_zip"   => "{BILLING ZIP}",
    "address_line1" => "{BILLING ADDRESS}",
    "address_line2" => "{BILLING ADDRESS 2}",

    "name"          => "{NAME ON CARD}",
    "number"        => "{CARD NUMBER}",
    "exp_month"     => "{EXPIRATION MONTH}",
    "exp_year"      => "{EXPIRATION YEAR}",
);

$this->load->library( 'stripe' );
$return = $this->stripe->add_card({STRIPE_CUSTOMER_ID},$card_object);
```

Hopefully that helps a bit in understanding how the stripe API works.